# Add reference to dll or reference to shared project in VS2017

Tags: msbuild, .net-core

When a solution has 20+ projects, which method should be used to:

1. minimize build order issues?
2. provided the fastest run time?
3. minimize issues when code is changing frequenty?

## Reference

`<Reference Include="Project2"><HintPath>..\..\Project2\bin\$(Configuration)\Project2.dll</HintPath></Reference>`

## ProjectReference

`<ProjectReference Include="..\..\Project2\Project2.csproj"><Name>Project2</Name></ProjectReference>`

Answer (score 1):

First of all, here's the difference between adding a `Reference` and adding a `Project Reference`:

- `Reference`s reference an **already built .dll** and therefore there is
  no way this .dll will be rebuilt.
- `Project Reference`s reference **another project, which can be rebuilt**
  (if it has changes).

Now to your question specifically:

---

1. By referencing already built .dlls (read: using `Reference`) you
   will not experience any build order issues (since they won't be
   built again).
2. Apart from that, it shouldn't make any difference at *runtime*
   whether you use `Reference`s or `Project Reference`s - however,
   there will be differences in *compile-time* as `References` will not
   be built.
3. For frequently changing code, you should use `Project Reference`s
   since they will be rebuild if changes occurred; already built .dlls
   won't. You will have to manually rebuild and add a reference to them
   again every time they change.